# moving django static files to aws S3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my Django app, I moved my static and media files to aws S3 bucket. Also, I deploy the app with elastic beanstalk. However, when I opened the admin page, it doesn't recognize static files. I am sure, static files uploaded to s3. I used following configurations;

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket_name'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'appName.custom_storages.MediaStorage'

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'appname.custom_storages.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
```

//custom_storages.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage


class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION


class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION
```

Comment: If you are using the Chrome browser, use inspector and select the Network tab, refresh the page and see where your page is expecting to get the static files from.

Comment: @ErionV thanks a lot, I resolved the problem with the help of your suggestion

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Comment: I guess you are using the book: Building Serveless Python Web Services with Zappa, right? If yes, can you help me to get it through? I can't run collectstatic. It is frozen and no error is emitted.